# Detecting whether something is (boost) range with SFINAE

Tags: c++, boost, sfinae, c++03

For logging code, I would like to detect whether given argument to a template function can be iterated over using the tools from [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) or not. Obviously I need to instantiate different code whether it is or not, so I need SFINAE, possibly (well, certainly) combined with boost::enable_if. I've tried detecting whether `begin` and `end` free functions are defined, like this:

```
namespace is_range_impl {
    template <typename T> T &make();
    struct any { template <class T> any(T const&); };
    struct not_range {};
    not_range begin(const any &);
    not_range end(const any &);
    struct no_type { char x[8]; };
    typedef char yes_type;
    template <typename T> yes_type check(const T &t);
    no_type check(const not_range &t);
    using boost::begin;
    using boost::end;
    template <typename T> struct is_range_impl {
        enum e {
            value = (sizeof(check(begin(make<T>()))) == sizeof(yes_type) &&
                     sizeof(check(end(make<T>()))) == sizeof(yes_type)),
        };
    };
}

template <typename T>
struct is_range : public is_range_impl::is_range_impl<T> {};

template <typename T>
typename boost::disable_if<is_range<T> >::type repr(std::ostream &s, const T &v)
{ ... }

template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if<is_range<T> >::type repr(std::ostream &s, const T &v)
{ ... }
```

But instead of silently failing when `boost::begin` and `boost::end` are not well-defined, it fails loudly with error that

```
'type' : is not a member of 'boost::mpl::eval_if_c<C,F1,F2>'
    [C=false, F1=boost::range_const_iterator<void *>, F2=boost::range_mutable_iterator<void *>]
```

in the following code in `boost/range/iterator.hpp:63`:

```
typedef BOOST_RANGE_DEDUCED_TYPENAME
        mpl::eval_if_c< is_const<C>::value,
                        range_const_iterator< typename remove_const<C>::type >,
                        range_mutable_iterator<C> >::type type;
```

(I have boost 1.51, but 1.52 lists no changes and 1.53 alpha lists two bug-fixes, but neither seems to be related)

So is there some better way to detect ranges? While I am stuck with some C++03 compilers and probably will be for quite a long while longer, I would like to make it as easily switchable to C++11 (where free `begin` and `end` available via ADL appear to be all that's needed).

Specifically the compilers are Visual C++ 9.0 and GCC 4.5. SFINAE support is adequate in both.

Comment: Which compilers?  SFINAE support varies with compiler.

Comment: @Yakk: We don't have *that* ancient compiler.

Comment: Some SFINAE techniques can fail in VS2010 as an example.  Probably not your problem, but...

Comment: So, at what step above does the error occur?  Does your `is_range` compile when fed an `int`?

Comment: @Yakk: Hm, I suspect it might actually be. VC++ 9.0 is VS2008 and since the `boost::range_iterator<T>::type` type that fails to compile is used in signature of `boost::begin`, I have expected SFINAE to kick in. But it didn't.

Comment: I've tried with `void *` in particular when it failed (instead of just compiling the no form). Actually the type is there in the error message I've included.

Comment: Here is a simple test using something like your code on [LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3So7xJ$1) -- testing `is_range` directly is a good step to take before doing the `repr` stuff.

Comment: @llonesmiz: Your deleted answer is correct one. The `has_range_iterator` metafunction appears to do the right thing; it does not appear to be documented, which is why I couldn't find it.

Comment: @JanHudec The problem with `has_range_iterator` is that returns true if the class has an `iterator/const_iterator` associated type or if `range_mutable_iterator/range_const_iterator` are specialized for it, but it doesn't check that either the class has `begin/end` as standalone or member functions.

Comment: @JanHudec It's pretty well hidden, but you can find `has_range_iterator`(amongst other metafunctions) [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/concept_implementation/semantics/metafunctions.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the metafunction you need to use is [`has_range_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/concept_implementation/semantics/metafunctions.html).

[Running on LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/744iw%243)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/range.hpp>

template <typename T>
typename boost::disable_if<boost::has_range_iterator<T> >::type repr(const T &, const std::string& name)
{ std::cout << name << " is not a range" << std::endl; }

template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::has_range_iterator<T> >::type repr(const T &, const std::string& name)
{ std::cout << name << " is a range" << std::endl; }

struct foo{};
struct bar
{
   typedef int iterator;
    typedef const int const_iterator;
    int begin(){ return 0;};
    int end(){ return 1;};
};


int main()
{
    int i;
    repr(i, "int");
    int array[10];
    repr(array, "int array");
    std::string str;
    repr(str, "std::string");
    foo f;
    repr(f, "foo");
    bar b;
    repr(b, "bar");

    std::pair<int, int> p;
    repr(p, "pair"); // it does make a mistake here, because std::pair<int, int> looks like range, but int is not valid iterator (cannot be dereferenced)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I couldn't find in the documentation. I's worth noting, that the `has_range_*iterator` asks specifically for mutable or const iterator only and that `boost::range_const_iterator<T>::type` and `boost::range_mutable_iterator<T>::type` turn out to work with SFINAE, only the boost::range_iterator<T> does not.

Comment: I've actually extended with asking for `typename std::iterator_traits<typename boost::range_const_iterator<T>::type>::pointer` to elliminate the `std::pair<int, int>` case.

Comment: The root of the OP problem was that the expression: boost::range_iterator<T>::type will not SFINAE. I'm running into this same thing with:
template<typename T>
typename boost::range_iterator<T>::type F(T & t) {
    return boost::range_iterator<T>(t);
}

  .....then another specialization for a non-range type...but the above one will cause an error if you use a non-range type. This solution very usefully points out has_range_iterator but range_iterator is still broken.